# Best way to just check endswith() in <s:if test=""> tag including equalsIgnore case in Struts2

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2, ognl

What is the best way to check if string ends with particular letters including equalsIgnore case.

I want to achieve something like below + ignore the case sensitivity only by using the struts2 tag and not the jstl tag.

```
<s:if test="(strDisplay.endsWith('XYZ'))">
```

Comment: In general, it's best to shy away from performing logic inside the views--it's harder to test, and keeps the logic scattered across concerns (e.g., view, business, model layers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 support function calls via OGNL.

```
<s:if test="strDisplay.toUpperCase().endsWith('XYZ')">
```

Comment: Thanks again Sir. Not tested it but I know that's authentic. expected a reply from you :)

Comment: afraid not before asking this question.... but thanks sir! wow.it is a good read on OGNL and related fire-works!!kudos

Answer (score 2):

I haven't work with Struts 2 tags, but I think code inside your expression language Java Code

So

Try this

```
strDisplay.toLowerCase().endsWith('XYZ'.toLowerCase())
```

Idea is simple you should either convert two Strings to `Uppercase` or `LowerCase` to achieve the `endsWithIgnoreCase`

Comment: I do have the Idea but I want to resolve it using s: tags only :). Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @yeppe you could replace this code in your expression language to achieve the same, as expression language will support java functions on java objects

Comment: Guess we have a solution thanks Pragnani for that piece of code!